# Local value, submitted value and value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, custom-component

We have `UIInput` component class and we wrote custom renderer for him.

```
@FacesRenderer(componentFamily = "javax.faces.Input", rendererType = "text")
public class TextFieldRenderer extends Renderer{
    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException{
        String ClientId= component.getClientId(context);
        String hint= (String) component.getAttributes().get("placeholder");
        String styleClass= (String) component.getAttributes().get("styleClass");
        String value =(String) component.getAttributes().get("value");
        ResponseWriter writer= context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.startElement("input", component);
        writer.writeAttribute("type", "text", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("name", ClientId, null);
        writer.writeAttribute("placeholder", hint, "hint");
        writer.writeAttribute("class", styleClass, "styleClass");
        writer.writeAttribute("value", ((UIInput) component).getValue(), "value");
        writer.endElement("input");
    }
    @Override
    public void decode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component){
        ExternalContext external= context.getExternalContext();
        Map<String,String> request=external.getRequestParameterMap();
        UIInput txt= (UIInput)component;
        String clientId= component.getClientId(context);
        String submittedValue= (String) request.get(clientId);
        txt.setSubmittedValue(submittedValue);
    }
}
```

and `index.xhtml` snippet

```
<h:form>
    <text:hintText id="ht" placeholder="hint" styleClass="geomClass fieldMarginClass">
        <f:validateLength minimum="4"/>
    </text:hintText>
    <h:commandButton value="sub" styleClass="geomClass buttonMarginClass"/>
    <h:message for="ht"/>
</h:form>
```

component.
As I understand after form submition value which typing to `hintText` will be assigned to a property `submittedValue` of `UIInput` instance by means of `setSubmittedValue()` method. 
Further at process_validation_phase we read value from `submittedValue` and apply our converter to him. If convertion success we passing converted value to method `setValue(Objec o)` and `submittedValue` will be `null` immideately. **So my question is**:

Where is converted value located? There is no value property of `UIInput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIInput` has a [`getConvertedValue()`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#getConvertedValue%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,java.lang.Object%29) method that retrieves the converted value. You can optionally override this method in your renderer to perform any additional conversion on the `submittedValue`. Otherwise, the method returns the raw `submittedValue`